# how to accept UIPanGestureRecognizer on all objects in NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, nsarray

i create a `UIScrollView` and i add `UIPanGestureRecognizer` and then in the scroll view i add some of `UIImageView` and then i add this `DragAndDrop2` on the images the problem is when i drag the image it is work but only one image i create an `NSArray` as in code but still the same problem the `UIPanGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop2` is accepted on the last object on the array so how i can apply this `UIPanGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop2` on all the `UIIMageView` in the array so whatever i select from those `UIImages` will accepted the `UIPanGestureRecognizer`
here is the code in the

UIImage+Stuff.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface UIImage (Stuff)

//
// return an UIImage from a CALayer
//
+ ( UIImage* ) grabImage:(CALayer*)layer;

@end
```

UIImage+Stuff.m

```
#import "UIImage+Stuff.h"

@implementation UIImage (Stuff)

+ ( UIImage* ) grabImage:(CALayer*)layer
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext ( layer.frame.size );
[ layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ];

    UIImage *grab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return grab;
}
@end
```

MainGameVC.h

```
@class APChartObject;

//
// drag status
//
typedef enum {
tDragStatusBegin = 0,
tDragStatusEnd,
tDragStatusIntersectIn,
tDragStatusIntersectOut
} tDragStatus;

@interface MainGameVC : UIViewController
//top menu scroll views
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *TopMenuViewer;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;

//drag and drop
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *DropView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *dragObject;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *cart;
@property (nonatomic, assign) tDragStatus dragging;
@property (nonatomic, strong) APChartObject *selectedModel;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectWheat;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectCorn;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectOnion;
@end
```

MainGameVC.m

```
#import "UIImage+Stuff.h"
@interface MainGameVC ()
{
UIImageView *_selectedView;
CGPoint _startPoint;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
// drag and drop touch
UIPanGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
[self.TopMenuViewer addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop];

NSArray *imageViewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:DragedObjectWheat,DragedObjectCorn,DragedObjectOnion, nil];

for(UIImageView *image in imageViewArray)
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:) ];
    [DragAndDrop2 setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];

    [image addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop2];
    image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}

}

    //+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    #pragma mark - View exchange
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    //
    // make the tricks.
    // Add a subview with the screenshot of selected and move around the screen
    //
    - ( void) cloneViewWithCenter:(CGPoint)point image:(UIImage*)grab
    {
        if ( _selectedView ) [ _selectedView removeFromSuperview ];

        _selectedView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:grab ];
        _selectedView.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, grab.size.width, grab.size.height);
        _selectedView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        [ self.view addSubview:_selectedView ];

        UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[ UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc ] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(moveObject:) ];
        [ pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1 ];
        [ _selectedView addGestureRecognizer:pan ];
    }


    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    #pragma mark - Refresh
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    //
    // refresh loop
    //
    - (void) refreshView
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^
         {
             CGRect r = _selectedView.frame;

             switch ( _dragging ) {
                 case tDragStatusBegin:
                     r.size.width  *= 1;
                     r.size.height *= 1;
                     break;
                 case tDragStatusEnd:
                     r.size.width  /= 1;
                     r.size.height /= 1;
                     break;
                 case tDragStatusIntersectIn:
                     r.size.width  = 1;
                     r.size.height = 1;

                     [ self finishDrag ];
                     break;
                 case tDragStatusIntersectOut:
                     _selectedView.center = _startPoint;
                     break;
             }

             _selectedView.frame = r;

         } completion:^(BOOL finished)
         {

             if ( _dragging == tDragStatusIntersectOut )
                 _selectedView.hidden = YES;

         }];
    }

    //
    // end drag
    //
    - (void) finishDrag
    {
        UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:_selectedView.image];
        [ self appendView:img ];
    }

    //
    // check for insertion in cart (or not)
    //
    - (void) checkForIntersection
    {
        //
        // ABS coords.
        //
        CGRect childRect = [ self.view convertRect:_selectedView.frame fromView:nil ];
        CGRect cartRect  = [ self.view convertRect:_cart.frame fromView:nil ];

        if ( CGRectIntersectsRect ( childRect, cartRect ))
        {
            self.dragging = tDragStatusIntersectIn;

        }
        else
        {
            self.dragging = tDragStatusIntersectOut;
        }
    }

    - (void) refreshCart
    {
        [ _cart setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_cart.contentOffset.x, 0) animated:YES ];
    }


    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    #pragma mark - Pan gesture
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+

    - ( void ) panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
    {

        CGPoint pInView = [ gesture locationInView:self.view ];
        //CGSize  pSize   = gesture.view.frame.size;

        if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan )
        {
            _startPoint = pInView;

    //        UIPanGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop2 = [[ UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc ] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:) ];
    //        [ DragAndDrop2 setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1 ];
    //        [DragedObjectCorn addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop2];
    //        [DragedObjectOnion addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop2];
    //        [DragedObjectWheat addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop2];
    //        
    //        NSArray *imageViewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:DragedObjectWheat,DragedObjectCorn,DragedObjectOnion, nil];
    //        for(UIImageView *image in imageViewArray)
    //        {
    //            [image addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop2];
    //            image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    //        }


    UIGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop2;
    // grab image
    //
     UIImage *grab = [UIImage grabImage: DragAndDrop2.view.layer];
            //
            // centering view
            //
            //pInView.x = pInView.x - pSize.width/2;
            //pInView.y = pInView.y - pSize.height/2;

            [ self cloneViewWithCenter:pInView image:grab ];

            self.dragging = tDragStatusBegin;
        }
        else if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged )
        {
            [ self moveObject:gesture ];
        }
        else if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
        {
            self.dragging = tDragStatusEnd;
            [ self checkForIntersection ];
        }
    }

    //
    // move draggable view around
    //
    - (void) moveObject:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
    {
        _selectedView.center = [ pan locationInView:_selectedView.superview ];
    }


    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    #pragma mark - Setter
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    - (void)setDragging:(tDragStatus)dragging
    {
        _dragging = dragging;
        [ self refreshView ];
    }


    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    #pragma mark - Chart view
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    //
    // recursively append view to scrollview.
    // If position already contains a view, shift and retry.
    //
    - (void) appendView:(id)view
    {
        //    UIView *v = view;
        //
        //    CGRect vRect = [ self.view convertRect:v.frame fromView:nil ];
        //
        //    for ( UIView *innerView in _cart.subviews )
        //    {
        //        CGRect cartRect = [ self.view convertRect:innerView.frame fromView:nil ];
        //
        //        if ( CGRectIntersectsRect(vRect, cartRect) )
        //        {
        //            CGRect r = v.frame;
        //            r.origin.x += r.size.width;
        //            v.frame = r;
        //
        //           _cart.contentSize = CGSizeMake(r.origin.x + 80, 80);
        //
        //            return [ self appendView:v ];
        //        }
        //    }
        //    
        [ _cart addSubview:view ];

        [ self performSelector:@selector(refreshCart) withObject:nil afterDelay:0 ];
    }
    @end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things:

1. You have to set your `UIImageView`s to `userInteractionEnabled = YES` since their user interaction property is disabled by default.
2. Each `UIImageView` should have its own `UIGestureRecognizer`.

I suggest editing your code like so:

```
NSArray *imageViewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:DragedObjectWheat,DragedObjectCorn,DragedObjectOnion, nil];

for(UIImageView *image in imageViewArray)
{
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:) ];
    [DragAndDrop2 setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];

    [image addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop2];
    image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

}
```

Also, I don't know what you're trying to do with this line, but this code's a bit suspicious:

```
UIImage *grab = [UIImage grabImage: DragAndDrop2.view.layer];
```

**Edit:**

Move that first block of code I wrote to your `viewDidLoad` then change these lines in `panDetected`:

```
UIGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop2;
UIImage *grab = [UIImage grabImage: DragAndDrop2.view.layer];
```

to this:

```
UIImage *grab = [UIImage grabImage: gesture.view.layer];
```

like in the github code, so that you're grabbing the image from the current gesture.

Comment: UIImage *grab = [UIImage grabImage: DragAndDrop2.view.layer];is taking the image that accepted on it the DragAndDrop2 "GestureRecognizer" and add it in this grap uiimage so that it move around in the screen, the problem all working fine except the GestureRecognizer is applied only on the last object in the array,while what u want is when i select any other uiimages in the array should GestureRecognizer apply on it

Comment: in this case it is work very fine but as u can see in my code the last object in the array is DragedObjectOnion, so it is the only one work so how every u select other images in the scroll view it is run and show only the image of onion

Comment: my project is about drag and drop items from scroll view, so drag it from scroll view and drop it in the uiview or other scroll view, but really it give me headache specially am beginner

Comment: @Mahmoud Did you try editing your code like I suggested in the first part of my answer?

Comment: yes and when i put the  UIPanGestureRecognizer inside the for statment the UIImage *grap .... line give error coz can not see the DragAndDrop2

Comment: @Mahmoud Yeah, you can declare DragAndDrop2 outside that method to avoid that error. (I'll edit my code to show you what I mean.) But I still don't get what you're trying to do with that last line... Not that it matters... If it works, then fine...

Comment: still the same problem, still only applied on the last object on the array and ignore the other objects, do u have any sample for drag and drop from UIScrollView

Comment: @Mahmoud Oh, shoot... Just realized I'd have to declare DragAndDrop2 within the loop to avoid that error with the dragging. But I can't help you resolve that error on the last line unless I understand what it does.

Comment: @Mahmoud I've edited it back to the way it was, but stuck that code at the end within the loop. Try it now. (I still can't guarantee that last line will work though since I don't know what it does.)

Comment: i depend on this code from this project https://github.com/elpsk/Shopping-Cart i change some, coz in this project shopping cart he intial the images programmatically while in my project i use the Builder

Comment: @Mahmoud In the project you linked to, that line is used to grab a particular image from an active gesture. I don't think it belongs in this section of your code unless there's a particular image you're trying to access out of all the gestures...and even then that code is unnecessary since you already have access to the image.

Comment: when i hint this line of code nothing work and can not access any images in the scroll view

Comment: @Mahmoud Could you update the question to include the entire method?

Comment: @Mahmoud Oh, so you tried to create the pan gesture recognizer in panDetected?? That's the problem right there. You can't trigger panDetected until you actually have panGesture recognizers.

Comment: @Mahmoud Move that first block of code I wrote to your viewDidLoad. And keep your grabImage line in the panDetected method.

Comment: it give me error for the DragAndDrop2 in the UIImage *grab = [UIImage grabImage: DragAndDrop2.view.layer];

Comment: @Mahmoud Did you keep a declaration of DragAndDrop2 within the panGesture method?

Comment: @Mahmoud I recommend just copying and pasting in the panGesture method from the github. But keeping the loop to add the gesture recognizers in the view did load like I said.

Comment: i move the first block to viewdidload and i declare the DragAndDrop2 in the panGesture method so this make the drag not working, i will update the code as i have in my computer

Comment: @Mahmoud Just updated my code to explain what you need to change.

Comment: one more question if you not mind, when u drag the image i want to replace it with a different image in the Dropped scroll view, for example when i drag the image of corn and drop it in the scroll view _Cart i want replace it with different image

Comment: @Mahmoud It looks like that code should go in checkForIntersection

Comment: i told you am beginner :-(, so i should change in the childRect under if statment?

Comment: i got it but it change the image i drag around the screen, what i mean is for example i drag image of corn so i will drop it in a the _cart which is scroll view, when i release it i do not want it stay same image of corn i want it change to other image so it is drag corn and release it different image

Comment: @Mahmoud You should probably post that as a separate question.

Comment: i already post the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27595468/how-to-replace-the-dragged-image-with-different-image-in-the-dropped

Comment: i already try in the checkForIntersection and also in the finishDrag method it is change but for all the image view is same image all i want is when i release image if it is corn, or wheat or water as in my images view it replace different image i choose it is like i say to the program if i choose corn and i release it in the dropped scroll view then change it to custom image i choose and then do more things....

Comment: if u interested here is the the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27636664/how-to-select-an-uiimgeview-from-nsarray

Comment: i already solved problem, i will update my code with all working methods