# How to select an UIImgeView from NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview

I have `UIImageView`s which are used as drag-able objects and they are in `NSArray` so and they work fine when drag them but what i want is when i drag them and finish dragging method instead of drop the image in the `UIImageView` i want replace it with custom image only in the dragged finish. so my problem is if i remove the `NSArray` and make it only IF statement it work fine but only take one  image and if i make it in `NSArray` as the code below it is take only last image (Close2) and not appended it

UIImage+Stuff.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

    @interface UIImage (Stuff)

    //
    // return an UIImage from a CALayer
    //
    + ( UIImage* ) grabImage:(CALayer*)layer;

    @end
```

UIImage+Stuff.m

```
    #import "UIImage+Stuff.h"

    @implementation UIImage (Stuff)

    + ( UIImage* ) grabImage:(CALayer*)layer
    {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext ( layer.frame.size );
    [ layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() ];

        UIImage *grab = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

        return grab;
    }
    @end
```

MainGameVC.h

```
    @class APChartObject;

    //
    // drag status
    //
    typedef enum {
    tDragStatusBegin = 0,
    tDragStatusEnd,
    tDragStatusIntersectIn,
    tDragStatusIntersectOut
    } tDragStatus;

    @interface MainGameVC : UIViewController

    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *TopMenuImages;
    //top menu scroll views
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *TopMenuViewer;
    @property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;

    //drag and drop
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIView *DropView;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIImageView *dragObject;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UIScrollView *cart;
    @property (nonatomic, assign) tDragStatus dragging;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) APChartObject *selectedModel;

    // all tools
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectBox;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectSand;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectSoil;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectWater;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectWheat;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectCorn;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectGarlic;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectLettuse;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectOnion;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectSugercane;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectTomato;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectCucumber;
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *DragedObjectBeans;
    @end
```

MainGameVC.m

```
    #import "UIImage+Stuff.h"
@interface MainGameVC ()
{
    UIImageView *_selectedView;
    CGPoint _startPoint;
    int selectedViewTag;
}

@end

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // drag and drop touch
    UIPanGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:)];
    [self.TopMenuViewer addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop];

    NSArray *imageViewArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:DragedObjectWheat,DragedObjectCorn,DragedObjectOnion, nil];

    for(UIImageView *image in imageViewArray)
    {
        UIPanGestureRecognizer *DragAndDrop2 = [[UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(panDetected:) ];
        [DragAndDrop2 setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1];

        [image addGestureRecognizer:DragAndDrop2];
        image.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    }

}

//+---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#pragma mark - View exchange
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    //
    // make the tricks.
    // Add a subview with the screenshot of selected and move around the screen
    //
    - ( void) cloneViewWithCenter:(CGPoint)point image:(UIImage*)grab ImageTag:(int)ToolTag
    {
    if ( _selectedView ) [ _selectedView removeFromSuperview ];
    selectedViewTag = ToolTag;
    _selectedView = [[ UIImageView alloc ] initWithImage:grab ];
    _selectedView.frame = CGRectMake(point.x, point.y, grab.size.width,   grab.size.height);
    _selectedView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    [ self.view addSubview:_selectedView ];

    UIPanGestureRecognizer *pan = [[ UIPanGestureRecognizer alloc ] initWithTarget:self  action:@selector(moveObject:) ];
    [ pan setMinimumNumberOfTouches:1 ];
    [ _selectedView addGestureRecognizer:pan ];
    }


    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    #pragma mark - Refresh
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    //
    // refresh loop
    //
    - (void) refreshView
    {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.2 animations:^
     {
         CGRect r = _selectedView.frame;

         switch ( _dragging ) {
             case tDragStatusBegin:
                 r.size.width  *= 1;
                 r.size.height *= 1;
                 break;
             case tDragStatusEnd:
                 r.size.width  /= 1;
                 r.size.height /= 1;
                 break;
             case tDragStatusIntersectIn:
                 r.size.width  = 1;
                 r.size.height = 1;

                 [ self finishDrag ];
                 break;
             case tDragStatusIntersectOut:
                 _selectedView.center = _startPoint;
                 break;
         }

         _selectedView.frame = r;

     } completion:^(BOOL finished)
     {

         if ( _dragging == tDragStatusIntersectOut )
             _selectedView.hidden = YES;

     }];
    }

    //
    // end drag
    //
    - (void) finishDrag
    {
    UIImageView *Tool;

    UIImage *ReplacedPhoto;
    UIImageView *imageView;
    switch (selectedViewTag)
    {

        case 1:

        {
            logic for image tag 1
                break;
        }
        case 2:

        {
            logic for image tag 2
                break;
        }

            Tool.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
            [self appendView:Tool];
    }

    //
    // check for insertion in cart (or not)
    //
    - (void) checkForIntersection
    {
        //
        // ABS coords.
        //
        CGRect childRect = [ self.view convertRect:_selectedView.frame fromView:nil ];
        CGRect cartRect  = [ self.view convertRect:_cart.frame fromView:nil ];

        if ( CGRectIntersectsRect ( childRect, cartRect ))
        {
            self.dragging = tDragStatusIntersectIn;

        }
        else
        {
            self.dragging = tDragStatusIntersectOut;
        }
    }

    - (void) refreshCart
    {
        [ _cart setContentOffset:CGPointMake(_cart.contentOffset.x, 0) animated:YES ];
    }


    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
    #pragma mark - Pan gesture
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+

    - ( void ) panDetected:(UIPanGestureRecognizer*)gesture
    {

        CGPoint pInView = [ gesture locationInView:self.view ];
        //CGSize  pSize   = gesture.view.frame.size;

        if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan )
        {
            _startPoint = pInView;
            UIImage *grab = [UIImage grabImage: gesture.view.layer];
            ToolTag = gesture.view.tag ;
            for (int i = 0; i>ToolTag; i++)
            {
                i = i+1;
                ToolTag = i;
            }
            //
            // centering view
            //
            //pInView.x = pInView.x - pSize.width/2;
            //pInView.y = pInView.y - pSize.height/2;

            [ self cloneViewWithCenter:pInView image:grab ImageTag:ToolTag ];

            self.dragging = tDragStatusBegin;
        }
        else if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged )
        {
            [ self moveObject:gesture ];
        }
        else if ( gesture.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded )
        {
            self.dragging = tDragStatusEnd;
            [ self checkForIntersection ];
        }
    }

    //
    // move draggable view around
    //
    - (void) moveObject:(UIPanGestureRecognizer *)pan
    {
        _selectedView.center = [ pan locationInView:_selectedView.superview ];
    }


// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#pragma mark - Setter
// +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    - (void)setDragging:(tDragStatus)dragging
    {
        _dragging = dragging;
        [ self refreshView ];
    }


    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+
#pragma mark - Chart view
    // +---------------------------------------------------------------------------+


    //
    // recursively append view to scrollview.
    // If position already contains a view, shift and retry.
    //
    - (void) appendView:(id)view
    {

        [ _cart addSubview:view ];

        [ self performSelector:@selector(refreshCart) withObject:nil afterDelay:0 ];
    }
    @end
```

Comment: what if you have 1000 images? you will put that much imageviews and connect them through IB?

Comment: Use IBOutletConnection instead of individual IBOutles, it will create an array for you, so that it would be easy for your to handle through array index to both arrays, imageArray and imageViewOutletConnection array.

Comment: `IBOutletCollection` is what you need.

Comment: can please provide code or update my code.... :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your header file declare a property to hold your imageview's and then hook them up in interface builder.

```
@interface YourViewController : UIViewController

@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutletCollection(UIImageView) NSArray *imageViews;
//...

@end
```

Now in the interface builder you need to connect all the imageView's to this new property.

[image]
[image]

Now you need to work with the `imageViews` collection. You can manually even tag the image which can be later used to check which image is dragged.

```
for (UIImageView *imageView in self.imageViews) {
  if (imageView.tag == 1){ 
  // .. Logic for image with tag 1
  }
  elseif (imageView.tag == 2){ 
  // .. Logic for image with tag 2
  }
}
```

Comment: not working it change all my image views to the first image in the for statment

Comment: i already done exactly as done in ur code but i got a problem all the images are change to same image which is the logic for image with tag 1 if make break between each IF and if i made it as u wrote with else if the both images show from tag 1 and tag 2 this is the code

Comment: so as of now i make it with break but all images in the array show same image in the logic of tag 1 so how i can make each image in the array show different image ??

Comment: @Mahmoud how did you added the tags? Also keep a break point and check what is the value of tags you are getting

Comment: i add the tags and i also make it in switch statement and i add a break point and it is work great load the tag image and load the image but the problem is when u drag any image it drag all the other images too so it is fire the full switch and add all images instead of replace picture depend on which image u drag....

Comment: i will update the code with full code coz this image from start has a UIPanGestureRecognizer in NSArray.. so will update the code to check it all ..

Comment: i update the code with full code for the drag and drop.... am working on it, and note the image as in the code when start event it go to _selectedView so i do my changes in the finishDrag method

Comment: I am not able to understand what error you are getting. It would be better if you can provide a prototype code via github or dropbox so that I could check it out.

Comment: the error is switch or else if whatever i use did not got break, so my app has images view and when i drag it is keep the image as it is and when drop event start should replace the image view image with different image so for example drag corn and when finish drop u see car image in the dropped scroll view, so it is fine and work fine but the problem is, all the images in the switch came one time, the switch statement fire all images for each image view  one time insted depend of user choose. got it

Comment: i already solved problem, i will update my code with all working methods

Comment: code under my question is updated with with working methods depending on your answer